# Ruby: Split string at character, counting from the right side

Tags: ruby, string, split

Short version -- How do I do Python rsplit() in ruby?

Longer version -- If I want to split a string into two parts (name, suffix) at the first '.' character, this does the job nicely:

```
name, suffix = name.split('.', 2)
```

But if I want to split at the *last* (rightmost) '.' character, I haven't been able to come up with anything more elegant than this:

```
idx = name.rindex('.')
name, suffix = name[0..idx-1], name[idx+1..-1] if idx
```

Note that the original name string may not have a dot at all, in which case name should be untouched and suffix should be nil; it may also have more than one dot, in which case only the bit after the final one should be the suffix.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

[`String#rpartition`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-rpartition) does just that:

```
name, match, suffix = name.rpartition('.')
```

It was introduced in Ruby 1.8.7, so if running an earlier version you can use [`require 'backports/1.8.7/string/rpartition'`](https://github.com/marcandre/backports) for that to work.

Comment: Thanks! String#rpartition is also present in Ruby 1.8.7.

Answer (score 5):

Put on the thinking cap for a while and came up with this regexp:

```
"what.to.do.now".split(/\.([^.]*)$/)
=> ["what.to.do", "now"]
```

Or in human terms "split at dot, not followed by another dot, at end of string".  Works nicely also with dotless strings and sequences of dots:

```
"whattodonow".split(/\.([^.]*)$/)
=> ["whattodonow"]
"what.to.do...now".split(/\.([^.]*)$/)
=> ["what.to.do..", "now"]
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I'd actually do:

```
/(.*)\.(.*)/.match("what.to.do")[1..2]
=> ["what.to", "do"]
```

or perhaps more conventionally,

```
s = "what.to.do"

s.match(/(.*)\.(.*)/)[1..2]
=> ["what.to", "do"]
```

Comment: I agree but I assumed he wanted a solution with split :)

Comment: Otherwise nice, but fails when s does not contain a dot.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the literal version of `rsplit`, you can do this (this is partly a joke, but actually works well):

```
"what.to.do".reverse.split('.', 2).map(&:reverse).reverse
=> ["what.to", "do"]
```

Comment: cool!  but i can do this.split(%r{(.+)\.})[1,2] which gives the sme result

Answer (score 0):

if this="what.to.do"  you can do this:

```
this.split(%r{(.+)\.})
```

and you'll get back

```
["", "what.to", "do"]
```

Comment: The empty element there is a bit annoying, and you can't stick [1..2] at the end to fix it, since "whattodo".split(%r{(.+)\.}) returns ["whattodo"].