# Creating a method that given a string (fname lname) returns the two

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-3

Given a string like "james bond" or "roger r burns" I'd like to create a method that takes the input and returns a first and last name:

For the cases above:

```
Input: James Bond
Returns:
  fname: james
  lname: bond

Input: Roger r Burns
Returns
  fname: Roger r
  lname: Burns

Input: Roger
Returns
  fname: Roger
  lname:

Input:
Returns
  fname:
  lname:
```

- Where an empty input does not error but returns back empty values.

How can I make a method that takes a single input and returns two variables?

Thanks

Comment: You do realize that your own example shows an incorrect case, correct? The guy's first name is "Roger", not "Roger R".

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. This has been updated.

Comment: looks like you need to use regular expressions or ruby split method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
def explode_name(str)
  !str.nil? && str.respond_to?(:split) ? ((2 - (a = str.split(' ', 2)).length).times { a << nil };a) : [nil,nil]
end

explode_name "Mr James Bond" #=> ["Mr", "James Bond"] 
explode_name "Mr Bond"       #=> ["Mr", "Bond"] 
explode_name "Mr"            #=> ["Mr", nil] 
explode_name ""              #=> [nil, nil] 
explode_name nil             #=> [nil, nil] 
explode_name 6               #=> [nil, nil]
```

[A comparison for programming's sake](http://pastie.org/1849284)

Answer (score 3):

You can try something like that:

```
last, first = str.reverse.split(' ', 2).collect{|s| s.reverse}
```

See also: [Ruby: Split string at character, counting from the right side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1844118/ruby-split-string-at-character-counting-from-the-right-side)
Working example: http://ideone.com/CA9aZ

Comment: Please be gentle with me, I don't actually know any Ruby, it took me about 15 minutes and much Googling

Comment: Very elegant, thought I get this error "NoMethodError (You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!" is there a way for it to handle empty strings?

Comment: @ColdTree - Thanks! I wouldn't know `:P`. Can't you check for nil? I assume that's something you do commonly, in any language.

Comment: You could to `str.to_s.reverse...`, since `nil.to_s` is an empty string.

Comment: Not be nit picky again, but you are enumerating over the string twice, then over the array twice.  It's twice as fast (albiet less elegant looking) to just have some error checking and case statements as the method I defined.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind, this method does no special case or error checking and makes **huge** assumptions on what the input is.

```
def name_split(string)
  split_string = string.split(' ')
  if split_string.count > 1      
    return split_string[0..split_string.count-2].join(" "), split_string.last
  else
    return split_string.first, nil # nil if there's no last name
  end
rescue NoMethodError
  return nil, nil
end

fname, lname = name_split("Roger Burns")   # => "Roger", "Burns"
fname, lname = name_split("Roger r Burns") # => "Roger r", "Burns"
fname, lname = name_split("Roger")         # => "Roger", nil
fname, lname = name_split(nil)             # => nil, nil
fname, lname = name_split(3)               # => nil, nil
```

Comment: Is there a way to handle the case when string is nil/empty, and have this method not error as that's actually acceptable?

Comment: Updated to be more resilient.

Comment: The question says expected output for `"Roger r Burns"` is `fname = "Roger r"`.

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to ever have an error be thrown, I'd prefer the method to just pass back nils

Comment: @ColdTree Well, then you can change the raise so that it returns nil, nil

Comment: @Kobi Thanks for the heads up, fixed [=

Comment: Thanks, that's good but it's just ignoring a middle name. Roger R Burns, is returning just Roger, Burns... And not Roger R, Burns

Comment: There ya go, returns the middle initial.  Hope that's what you want, it's a little bit slower now because it has to create a `Range` object to figure out which strings go in it.

Comment: Of course it doesn't get my name right (last name Van Stone), but that was part of the "huge assumptions" you are making.

Comment: @Kathy Van Stone, try my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

```
def sname(name)
  name.match(/^(\w+)(?:.*\b(\w+))?$/)[1..2] rescue raise ArgumentError
end

sname "James Bond" # => ["James", "Bond"]
sname "James J. Bond" # => ["James", "Bond"]
sname "James" # => ["James", nil]
sname "" # => raises ArgumentError
```

Comment: Also, for your third usecase when there is no last name, that's ok I don't want to raise an error. Given a string if empty, return nothing which is fine. If just a first name that's fine just return only a first name. Thoughts?

Comment: I ran this in `irb` using `ruby -v 1.9.2` and running the `regex` takes almost 3 times as long.

Comment: Edited. This is like you want now?

Answer (score 0):

You could add another variable for the middle name. If exists then assign the middle initial to part of the first name variable. If it does not exist then move the middle variable (which is actually the last name) to the last name variable.

Answer (score 0):

How'z about this?

```
def split_name(full_name)
  name = full_name || ''
  split = name.split(' ')
  split.push(nil) if split.length < 2
  return split[0, split.length - 1].join(' '), split.last  
end

names = ['James Bond', 'Roger r Burns', 'Roger', '']
names.each do |name|
  puts "Input: #{name}"
  output = split_name(name)
  puts "First name: #{output.first}"
  puts "Last name: #{output.last}"
  puts "****"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
def split_names(name)
  parts = name.blank? ? ["", ""] : name.split(" ")
  parts << "" if parts.size == 1
  [parts[0..-2].join(" "), parts.last]
end
```