# Rails split by last delimiter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, split, delimiter

I want to be able to split strings into 2 elements, because each string would contain at least one delimiter.

Example: `"hello_world"`. If I apply `.split("_")` then I receive: `["hello", "world"]`.

The problem arises when I have a string with two or more delimiters. Example `"hello_to_you"`. 
I want to receive: `["hello_to", "you"]`.

I know about the limit option for the split function: `.split("_", 2)`, but it produces: `["hello", "to_you"]`.

So, basically, I would need to split the entire string ONLY with the last delimiter ("_").

Comment: Same question worded differently: [Ruby: Split string at character, counting from the right side](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1844118/ruby-split-string-at-character-counting-from-the-right-side)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
'hello_to_you'.split /\_(?=[^_]*$)/
```

Comment: Thank you. Clean, simple and works good! Just what I needed!

Comment: Don't escape `_` though. Also isn't `/_(?!.*_)/` easier?

Answer (score 9):

This is exactly what [`String#rpartition`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-rpartition) does:

```
first_part, _, last_part = 'hello_to_you'.rpartition('_')
first_part # => 'hello_to'
last_part # => 'you'
```

Comment: Awesome, i didnt know this method

Answer (score 2):

```
class String
  def split_by_last_occurrance(char=" ")
    loc = self.rindex(char)
    loc != nil ? [self[0...loc], self[loc+1..-1]] : [self]
  end
end

"test by last_occurrance".split_by_last  #=> ["test by", "last"]
"test".split_by_last_occurrance               #=> ["test"]
```

Comment: Dont' reinvent the wheel, see my answer instead